# PDO returns empty data

Tags: php, pdo

I'm wondering why my PDO statement returns 1 row but the data is empty when i assign it to a variable.

I have this:

```
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(uid) AS total,uid FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND pass = ?"); 
    try {
        $stmt->execute(array($temp[0],$temp[1]));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e -> getMessage(); exit;
    }

    $row = $stmt -> fetch();
    if(!$row['total']){
        echo json_encode(0);
    } else {            
        $_SESSION['userData'] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($_SESSION['userData']); 
    }
```

When i echo the session it returns `[]`

Is it because i do a fetch before the fetchAll ? If so how can i change it prevent that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify your code like this

currently what you are doing is first you check no. of rows by **PDO::Fetch()** and later you fetch that row with `PDOStatement::fetchAll`

you can apply below approach which is more clear

First count the row using [`PDOStatement::rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a
>   DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement.

and then use [`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) to fetch the row.

```
$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: This is not a very portable approach though, not all database engines will have a working `rowCount()` on `SELECT` statements; in fact, your quote from the manual clearly doesn't mention `SELECT` either :)

Comment: @Jack Yes, But he is working with `PDO` and `PDO` has such a great functionality.

Comment: @diEcho That doesn't make any sense, the documentation for PDO::rowCount() specifically mentions it's not portable for SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 $row = $stmt -> fetch();
```

to

```
 $row = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

That returns all the rows as an associative array. Just loop through the array, and you can obtain the result. 
 
Hope this helps.